# Grails Tomcat Render GSP template

Tags: templates, grails

In a controller i have ,,

```
render(template: 'bookingHeader', model: [memberInstance:memberInstance,bookingInstance: bookingInstance, eventInstance: eventInstance])

render(template: 'bookingAccounts', model: [memberAccountInstanceList:memberInstance.memberAccounts])
```

which correctly renders info to the screen  ..

In a gsp I have
    g:render template="bookingheader" model="'booking':bookingInstance,'member':memberInstance]"/>

Both work fine in my test environment (Intellij ) but the gsp tag fails when
deployed in a war to tomcat ..  So i moved t template to a common directory and
put an

explicit reference in ..

```
g:render template="/common/bookingheader" model="['booking': bookingInstance,
```

'member': memberInstance]"/>

it still failed with  ..

Error 500: Error processing GroovyPageView: Template  not found for name
[/common/bookingheader] and path  [/common/_bookingheader.gsp] at 
/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/booking/details.gsp:33
Servlet: grails
URI: /apollo/grails/booking/details.dispatch
Exception Message: Template not found for name  [/common/bookingheader] and path
[/common/_bookingheader.gsp] at 
/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/booking/details.gsp:33

Caused by: Error processing GroovyPageView:  Template not found for name
[/common/bookingheader] and path  [/common/_bookingheader.gsp] at 
/WEB-INF/grails-app/views/booking/details.gsp:33

Class: gsp_apollo_bookingdetails_gsp
At Line: [33]
Code Snippet:

My environment is Grails 1.2.2 deploying to Tomcat 6 .. This is really causing
me some grief ..

I checked the web app directories and as far as i can see the GSP'S are where
they should be ..  in Tomcat 6.0\webapps\apollo\WEB-INF\grails-app\views\common

Can anyone shed any light  ???

Answer (score 3):

In the controller you're using CamelCase 'bookingHeader' but in the GSP it is all lower case 'bookingheader'.

Comment: Your right .. I'd actually figured that out myself after a frustrating couple of hours :( .. It's just the fact that it worked in my test environment kind of threw me .. Thanks for taking the time to help though  ..